# How to tell composer to use branch when tags do not exist?

Tags: php, version-control, composer-php

I am building a php app and I require a package `foo\bar` that I want to load with composer.

`foo\bar` is currently at version `1.2.0` but it has a branch `new-features-for-2.0.0` which has features that I need. `foo\bar` version `2.0.0` will be released soon™.

Can I tell composer "`require "^2.0.0"` when it exists, otherwise `require "dev-new-features-for-2.0.0"`"?

I did have a look at [composer aliases](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md) but I do not understand that enough to know how to apply that to this situation.

P.S. Suggestions for a different workflow are also welcome!

Comment: You don't require the new version until it releases, and ideally you've tested your own code against that new version.

Comment: Either require the dev version, or require the properly released version. After the dependencies are resolved, Composer won't change them without an explicit command

Comment: What did not work for you? Where is the repository of that package? Which SCM utility is in use (different than `git(1)`?)?